# Find $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Suppose $f(x)$ be a periodical function defined over $\mathbb{R}$, bounded nearby $x=0$ and satisfy $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}[2f(x)-f(2x)]=0.$ Find $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{x}.$

Let $T$ be a positive period of $f(x)$. Then $2f(x)-f(2x)=2f(x+nT)-f[2(x+nT)]$, where $n=1,2,\cdots.$ Hence $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}[2f(x)-f(2x)]=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left[2f(x+nT)-f(2(x+nT))\right]=0,$ which implies $2f(x)=f(2x)$ holding for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Further, $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}f(2x)=\cdots=\dfrac{1}{2^n}f(2^nx).$ How to go on?

Comment: The same question was asked recently: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3915459/42969.

Comment: @MartinR: I have seen that user (asker of the question you linked) posting another exact duplicate with no context. Don't know what's going on. Same question being posted by two users in a span of few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have most of what you need:  you have deduced for all $x$
$$ f(x) = 2^{-n} f(2^n x). $$
Replace $x$ with $2^{-n}x$ and you obtain for any $x \in [0,T]$,
$$ f(x) = 2^n f(2^{-n}x ). $$
Now use the boundedness of $f$ in the neighbourhood of $x=0$.  There exists $b > 0 $ and $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x)| \leqslant b $ whenever $|x| < \delta$.  Because $f$ is periodic, we can find a fixed integer $n$ such that $0 \leqslant 2^{-n} x  < \delta$ for all $x \in [0,T]$: simply choose $n > \log (T / \delta) / \log 2$.  Then, for every $x \in [0,T]$
$$
|f(x)| = |2^n f(2^{-n}x)| \leqslant 2^n b$$
and by periodicity, it follows $f(x)$ is bounded by $2^nb$ for all $x$.  Then
$$ \left\lvert \frac{f(x)}{x} \right\rvert \leq \frac{ 2^nb}{|x|} \to 0 \quad\text{as}\quad  x \to \infty.$$